# Need .bat script to copy file to multiple pcs

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I have a requirement that I need to copy a file to multiple PCs frequently. It has to first check if the file exists, if yes then rename it with DATE and if no, then copy.

I prepared a txt file with all IP's (complist.txt).

I am looking to create a parameter file where user can enter all file/folder locations. The batch code should not be touched by user.

I did the following test:

1. New file to be copied.

   ```
   FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN (C:\Atiq\test_batch_copy\Complist.txt) DO XCOPY /F /Y "C:\Atiq\test_batch_copy\file.txt" "\\%%~A\applsys\Test\"
   ```
2. To rename file if existing

   ```
   FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN (C:\Atiq\test_batch_copy\Complist.txt) DO COPY /Y "C:\Atiq\test_batch_copy\file.txt" "\\%%~A\applsys\Test\file_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.txt"
   ```

Both are working as expected. I would like to maintain one batch for both "Copy new file" and "Rename file if existing".

Please help.

---

Please let me know if this is the right way to code. Its working. I just want to seperate the parameters in seperate file and call the code in other file. Is it possible?

```
@echo off;
set source=C:\Atiq\test_batch_copy\file.txt
set target=\\%%~s\applsys\Test\file.txt


set IPList=C:\Atiq\test_batch_copy\Complist.txt
set today=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%

for /f "tokens=*" %%s in (%IPList%) do (
 if exist %target% (
 COPY /Y "C:\Atiq\test_batch_copy\file.txt" "\\%%~s\applsys\Test\file_%today%.txt"
 XCOPY /F /Y "%source%" "\\%%~s\applsys\Test\" 
 ) 

 if not exist %target% (
  XCOPY /F /Y "%source%" "\\%%~s\applsys\Test\" 
 )
)
```

Comment: Making ``today`` a separate variable and setting it in a separate statement is a good step.  And thank you for breaking the 180-character long command into shorter lines, and indenting.  But please indent consistently: the `COPY` and the first `XCOPY` (under `if exist %target%`) should be indented.  And indent deeper: four spaces is typical.  And try to be clearer.  Every time I read “copy the file if it doesn’t exist”, my head explodes a little.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  And your question wanders all over the place.  Are you totally lost and up the creek?  No, you obviously know how to loop over the contents of a file and do `IF`-`EXIST`-`THEN`.  Where are you stuck?  What do you need help with? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.